# Any good way to enforce not null many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, relational-database

For example, there are two tables which have many-to-many relationship.

```
create table Item (ID int primary key, .....)
create table Category (ID int primary key, ......)
```

And there is a relationship table

```
create table ItemCategory (
    ItemID int not null foreign key references Item (ID), 
    CategoryID int not null foreign key references Category (ID) )
```

Is it possible to add a constraint to make sure an `Item` has at least one `Category`? That is, there must be at least one row in `ItemCategory` table for each Item.

Answer (score 1):

Not at the table/fk level.

An alternative is to perform all `Item` inserts via a stored procedure that also inserts to `ItemCategory`, and perform all `ItemCategory` deletes via a stored procedure that won't delete if it's an Item's last record.

Comment: update/insert stored procedures are easy to be bypassed. I'm wondering if there is any way to enforce it using triggers/rule, etc.